# Filter_all with differing condition for each column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have the following vector

```
vec1 = c(0.001, 0.05, 0.003, 0.1)
```

and a data frame

```
df = data_frame( x = seq(0.001, 0.1, length.out = 10), y = seq(0.03, 0.07, length.out = 10), z = seq(0, 0.005, length.out = 10), w = seq(0.05, 0.25, length.out = 10))
```

I would like to filter `df` such that the output would contain the rows of `df` for which, in each column, the minimum value would be the corresponding value of `vec1 - 0.05`, and the maximum would be `vec1 + 0.05`.

So in this example, only the first 4 rows satisfy this condition (in `x` I allow `-0.049 to 0.501` based on the first entry of `vec1`, in `y` I allow `0` to `0.1` based on the second entry, and so on).

I am sure this can be done with `filter_all` and `(.)`, something along the lines of

```
filter_all(df, all_vars(. >= (vec1(.) - 0.05) &  . <= (vec1(.) + 0.05))))
```

But this doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` on the dataframe and pass it along with `vec1` and check which of the values satisfy the criteria and select only those rows where all of the columns have `TRUE` value in it.

```
df[rowSums(mapply(function(x, y) x > (y-0.05) & x < (y+0.05),
                                           df, vec1))  == ncol(df), ]

#      x      y        z      w
#   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 0.0120 0.0344 0.000556 0.0722
#2 0.0230 0.0389 0.00111  0.0944
#3 0.0340 0.0433 0.00167  0.117 
#4 0.0450 0.0478 0.00222  0.139
```

Comment: Or `rowSums(df > (vec1[col(df)] - 0.05) & df < (vec1[col(df)] + 0.05)) == ncol(df)`